# Clojure: Proper condp Usage

Tags: syntax, clojure, functional-programming, conditional-statements, hiccup

I'm rewriting my History of the World website (history.clmitchell.net) in clojure and making great progress. I've reached the point where I need to use a conditional to output hiccup code for declaring CSS links based on which page I'm loading. I've pored over the docs but can't figure this out:

```
(defn cssfiles
  "load sets of CSS files depending on which page is being served"
  [pageName]
  (condp = pageName
         "index" (hic/include-css "/css/hcspry.css"
                                  "/css/menus.css"
                                  "/css/filter.css"
                                  "/css/wc3xhtml1.css")
         "add" (hic/include-css "/css/hcspry.css"
                                "/css/menus.css"
                                "/css/addform.css")
         "map" (hic/include-css "/css/hcspry.css"
                                "/css/menus.css"
                                "/css/SpryCollapsiblePanel.css"
                                "/css/SpryAccordion.css")
         "chart" (hic/include-css "/css/hcspry.css"
                                  "/css/menus.css"
                                  "/css/filter.css"
                                  "/css/cha.css")
         "learn" (hic/include-css "/css/hcspry.css"
                                  "/css/menus.css"
                                  "/css/filter.css"
                                  "/css/wc3xhtml1.css"
                                  "/css/doc.css")
         "changes" (hic/include-css "/css/hcspry.css"
                                    "/css/menus.css"
                                    "/css/filter.css"
                                    "/css/wc3xhtml1.css"
                                    "/css/clg.css")
         "seek" (hic/include-css "/css/hcspry.css"
                                 "/css/menus.css"))
  (println (str  "PRGMR. MSG: net.clm.history.pages.snippets.clj::(defn cssfiles [" pageName "]): unknown parameter or parameter not processed properly.")))
```

Question: what is the proper syntax for this kind of function?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? If you're trying to have `println` as the `:else` condition, then you need to "slurp" it inside the previous set of parentheses (ones belonging to `condp`).

Comment: @dskrvk I think you're right; I'll try that 1st thing tomorrow.

Comment: It isn't clear fro your question what it is you cannot figure out. What is your function not doing which you expect it should be doing?

Comment: This isn't a question. It's a statement of some things you are doing, and then a paste of your code. What are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

You could define your page-css mapping as a separate, plain data structure and avoid the repetitive call to hic/include-css:

```
(def page-css-mapping
  {"index"   ["/css/hcspry.css"
              "/css/menus.css"
              "/css/filter.css"
              "/css/wc3xhtml1.css"]
   "add"     ["/css/hcspry.css"
              "/css/menus.css"
              "/css/addform.css"]
   "map"     ["/css/hcspry.css"
              "/css/menus.css"
              "/css/SpryCollapsiblePanel.css"
              "/css/SpryAccordion.css"]
   "chart"   ["/css/hcspry.css"
              "/css/menus.css"
              "/css/filter.css"
              "/css/cha.css"]
   "learn"   ["/css/hcspry.css"
              "/css/menus.css"
              "/css/filter.css"
              "/css/wc3xhtml1.css"
              "/css/doc.css"]
   "changes" ["/css/hcspry.css"
              "/css/menus.css"
              "/css/filter.css"
              "/css/wc3xhtml1.css"
              "/css/clg.css"]
   "seek"    ["/css/hcspry.css"
              "/css/menus.css"]})

(defn cssfiles
  "load sets of CSS files depending on which page is being served"
  [pageName]
  (if-let [css-files (get page-css-mapping pageName)]
    (apply hic/include-css css-files)
    (println (str "PRGMR. MSG: net.clm.history.pages.snippets.clj::(defn cssfiles [" pageName "]): unknown parameter or parameter not processed properly."))))
```

Now you can also store your mapping as plain data structure (eg. as EDN file or in Datomic) instead of having it hard coded.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you're not sure what the function `cssfiles` is doing?  In that case, the function says:

If my argument `pagename` is equal to the string `"index"`, then execute the function `include-css` that can be found in the namespace abbreviated by `hic`, passing this function the arguments `"/css/hcspry.css"`, `"/css/menus.css"`, ..., and returning the resulting value as my (i.e. `cssfiles`') return value.

If instead `pagename` is equal to `"add"`, then excecute `include-css` with a different set of arguments ..., returning the resulting value .... (etc.)

And so on for other strings that are predictable values of `pagename`.

But if `pagename` doesn't match any of the strings I tested, then execute the `println` statement at the end of the `condp` expression in order to print out an error message.

See the documentation for [`condp`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/condp) for more on the syntax.  I'm happy to provide more details if needed, though.

Comment: @dskrv is correct about the misplaced parentheses.  Everything I said applies with the correction.

Answer (score 0):

dskrvk was right: the println form was not within the condp form; here's the corrected frunction:

```
(defn cssfiles
  "load sets of CSS files depending on which page is being served"
  [pageName]
  (condp = pageName
         "index" (hic/include-css "/css/hcspry.css"
                                  "/css/menus.css"
                                  "/css/filter.css"
                                  "/css/wc3xhtml1.css")
         "add" (hic/include-css "/css/hcspry.css"
                                "/css/menus.css"
                                "/css/addform.css")
         "map" (hic/include-css "/css/hcspry.css"
                                "/css/menus.css"
                                "/css/SpryCollapsiblePanel.css"
                                "/css/SpryAccordion.css")
         "chart" (hic/include-css "/css/hcspry.css"
                                  "/css/menus.css"
                                  "/css/filter.css"
                                  "/css/cha.css")
         "learn" (hic/include-css "/css/hcspry.css"
                                  "/css/menus.css"
                                  "/css/filter.css"
                                  "/css/wc3xhtml1.css"
                                  "/css/doc.css")
         "changes" (hic/include-css "/css/hcspry.css"
                                    "/css/menus.css"
                                    "/css/filter.css"
                                    "/css/wc3xhtml1.css"
                                    "/css/clg.css")
         "seek" (hic/include-css "/css/hcspry.css"
                                 "/css/menus.css")
         (println (str  "PRGMR. MSG: net.clm.history.pages.snippets.clj::(defn cssfiles [" pageName "]): unknown parameter or parameter not processed properly."))))
```

Comment: It's not clear why this is an answer @Quasaur.  I was never sure what the original question was.